# fMRI visualization on the browser

Tags: canvas, webgl, imaging, xtk, medical

I've been searching for a while and I couldn't find any implementation of this. Are there any examples of functional Magnetic Resonance Imaging data visualization using XTK? Actually, I would be interested in any example running on web browsers, even using other technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Which file format are your trying to visualize? If I am not mistaking, fMRI is just a DICOM series through time, right?

You could split the time points and load them separately in XTK.

My 2 cts

Comment: Yes you are right. It seems the most straight forward approach, maybe using webworkers to load the time points separately without blocking anything else. I would like to be able to visit the data in space and time interactively. Since I couldn't find examples, I'm afraid there may be intrinsic complications with this feature. Would data size be an issue?

Comment: Yes if the data is too big, you will need some server side logic, there is a limit on how much data you can load in your browser... You can also look into local storage and indexdatabases (HTML5 new stuff) Web Workers might work to load the data, you just have to be carefull and make sure they do not crash your client, if too many of them are running...